# How to set value for input 'textfield' with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs, textfield

i have a method in my `openDB.js` logic class:

```
getUserByUsername: function(username) {
        return this.getUsers(username).then(function(users) {
            return users[ username ];
        });
    },
```

i'm getting there user with a lot of properties/values.
i have a extjs input `'textfield'`, and i want to get in `'value'` of textfield some user information.
i know that all follow parameters has values (it is codesnippet from `openDB.js` CreateUser function):

```
.addParameter("DEPARTMENT", user.department)
            .addParameter("FAX", user.fax)
            .addParameter("FIRSTNAME", user.firstName)
            .addParameter("FUNCTION", user["function"])
            .addParameter("LASTNAME", user.lastName)
            .addParameter("LOCATION", user.location)
            .addParameter("MAIL", user.mail)
            .addParameter("MOBILE", user.mobile)
            .addParameter("PASSWORD", user.password)
```

i know it because its possible to check it with setTitle like this:

```
 openDB.getUserByUsername(user.username).then(function(userDetails)
        {
            debugger;
            me.setTitle("Welcome " + userDetails.department + "!");
        });
```

its works fine with all properties.
**but how to do it with 'textfield' value ????**

```
 items: [{
                        xtype: "form",
                        bodyPadding: 5,
                        border: false,
                        defaults: {
                            xtype: "textfield",
                            inputType: "text",
                            anchor: "100%"
                        },
                        items: [{
                            fieldLabel: 'Firstname:',
                            id: 'firstName',
                            readOnly: true,
                            value: user.firstName,
                            name: "username"
                        }, {
                            fieldLabel: 'E-Mail:',
                            id: 'email',
                            value: 'user.email',
                            name: "email"
                        }, {
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118350/how-to-get-user-input-value-from-ext-window-textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after couple hours of Fitign with that -> BEST SOLUTION EVER:

```
items: [{
                        fieldLabel: 'Firstname:',
                        id: 'firstName',
                        readOnly: true,
                        value: user.firstName,
                        name: "username"
}]
... 
var name = Ext.getCmp('firstName').setValue('JohnRambo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getValue` method on the field.

```
var f = new Ext.form.field.Text({
    renderTo: document.body,
    value: 'foo'
});
console.log(f.getValue());
```

Comment: how can i do it with textfield/value and this function getUserByUsername: function(username) {
        return this.getUsers(username).then(function(users) {
            return users[ username ];
        });
    },???